# Laravel 5 Token mismatch on POST request

Tags: php, laravel, message-queue, laravel-5, iron

It is appening something that is very strange:

I'm implementing in Laravel 5, the Iron message queue in order to differ the request, from long tasks executions.
Once I've pushed a message into the Iron's queue, it sends a POST request to a predefined route, in order to wake up the long running process (Push Queue approach).

I've this route file:

```
Route::post('queue/receive', function()
    {
        //start long task exec
        return Queue::marshal();
    });

/* garantisco il logout agli utenti*/
Route::get('auth/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');

/* redirect degli utenti loggati */
Route::group(['middleware' => 'guest'], function()
{

    Route::get('/', 'WelcomeController@index');

    Route::controllers([
        'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
        'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
    ]);
});

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function()
{
    Route::get('home', 'HomeController@index');
});
```

The first route defined is the endpoint that IronMQ will call.
I know that token mismatch is a popular problem using the "VerifyCsrfToken" middleware (same as filter in L4).
The incredible thing is that I've disabled this middleware, but the problem persists.
This is my kernel's middlewares:

```
class Kernel extends HttpKernel {

    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * @var array
     */

    protected $middleware = [
        'Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode',
        'Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies',
        'Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse',
        'Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession',
        'Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession',
        //'LabelCreator\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken',
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => 'LabelCreator\Http\Middleware\Authenticate',
        'auth.basic' => 'Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth',
        'guest' => 'LabelCreator\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated',
    ];

}
```

As you can see, "VerifyCsrfToken" is disabled but testing the post request from local env, now I'm getting this error:

```
    DecryptException in Encrypter.php line 142:
Invalid data.
in Encrypter.php line 142
at Encrypter->getJsonPayload('') in Encrypter.php line 92
at Encrypter->decrypt('') in IronQueue.php line 214
at IronQueue->parseJobBody('') in IronQueue.php line 173
at IronQueue->marshalPushedJob() in IronQueue.php line 159
at IronQueue->marshal()
at call_user_func_array(array(object(IronQueue), 'marshal'), array()) in QueueManager.php line 223
at QueueManager->__call('marshal', array()) in Facade.php line 207
at QueueManager->marshal() in Facade.php line 207
at Facade::__callStatic('marshal', array()) in routes.php line 17
at Queue::marshal() in routes.php line 17
at RouteServiceProvider->{closure}()
at call_user_func_array(object(Closure), array()) in Route.php line 153
at Route->runCallable(object(Request)) in Route.php line 128
at Route->run(object(Request)) in Router.php line 691
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 141
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 101
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 693
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 660
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 618
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 210
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 141
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 55
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 61
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 36
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 40
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 42
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 101
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 111
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 84
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
```

I've tried to comment the others middlewares, but the problem persists.
What Iron is doing is a simple POST request to my endpoint, like webhooks do.
What is the problem?
I don't think is a session's problem, because Iron is a simple thirdy part service that call an endpoint, and if it remains a "guest" client for my app it is ok.

Can anyone help me?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem:
I was testing the endpoint in local without a POST request payload, so the decryption doesn't work properly, but sniffing which payload IronMQ sends, using [RequestBin](http://requestb.in/) (very useful tool), I've added the same payload to local test request, and now it works.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Could you please tell me how you did it? I'm having same trouble with IronMQ and Laravel currently.

Comment: @PeteHouston what is your problem?

Comment: I got TokenMismatchException when IronMQ post to queue route. So I managed to handle it by excluding the queue route from CSRF token check. Do you have any better solution?

Comment: @PeteHouston my solution is: delete the VerifyCsrfToken middleware from the queue route, but use a custom middleware that verify a secret key as get param in order to keep secure the route.